# In @angular's source code, why does NgForm use an already resolved promise in its functions?

Tags: angular, promise

I've started reading through the @angular source code, partially to learn, and partially because some of the docs seem to be missing things. Amongst the forms directives, I've come across blocks of code like this:

```
const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
...
export class NgForm extends ControlContainer implements Form {
  ...
  addControl(dir: NgModel): void {
    resolvedPromise.then(() => {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

This specific example is from [ng_form](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts), and this pattern is repeated throughout this file. Every function that this is used in has no return value, which I assume is relevant.

What's the purpose of using this resolvedPromise? My understanding here is that, since resolvedPromise has already completed before this function is ever called, the callback provided to the `then` function will be executed immediately. In which case, why bother using the Promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then()` executes code async but scheduled as microtask instead of a new task in the event queue.

See for example https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/ for a demonstration of the difference.

Before the current event is completed and the next event processed, not only the current event handler, but also the microtask queue needs to be processed completely.

This way code can be executed async without other event handlers interfering and causing race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of change detections.

They're saying that NgZone has patched all the asynchronous functions in the browser.

That would mean The Promise is patched as well, which means when the promise is resolved , angular would run a change detection cycle.

I guess this is they're way of making sure for example addControl function is hooked up in NgZone hence no need to manually detect changes.

I could be wrong though, need some investigation:P

Answer (score 0):

They are forcing an additional change detection run to make sure that changes were propagated correctly. See comment section for [`NgModel`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/69dfcf73853d63f4fbaf4c8f44a7dbff689bbc81/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is absolutely correct that this promise will already have been resolved when it reaches those functions which are using "resolvedPromise". Just to refresh the concept of Promise.Resolve from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Using_the_static_Promise.resolve_method):

> the Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is
>   resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a
>   "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable,
>   adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be
>   fulfilled with the value.

So why bother using Promise in this case? Simply because when you want to have an async operation, you go with this kind of approach where you know in advance that there is nothing to resolve. Hope that helps.